# why am i getting : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Java Code :

```
package Package;

public class IntArray {
private native int sumArray(int[] arr);

public static void main(String args[]) {
    IntArray p = new IntArray();
    int arr[] = new int[10];
    for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    int sum = p.sumArray(arr); // pass the array to the c function sumArray
    System.out.println("Sum is : " + sum);
}

 static { // 17th statement
     System.loadLibrary("IntArray");
 }
}
```

C code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "Package_IntArray.h"

jint Java_Package_IntArray_sumArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jintArray arr)
          {
             jint buf[10];
             jint i, sum = 0;
             (*env)->GetIntArrayRegion(env, arr, 0, 10, buf);
             for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                 sum += buf[i];
             }
             return sum;
          }
```

Then i run the command :

```
java -Djava.library.path=W:\elita\jnitesters\workspace\c\IntArray\bin\Debug Package.IntArray
```

to which i get the following exceptions :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Package.IntArray.sumArray([I)I
    at Package.IntArray.sumArray(Native Method)
    at Package.IntArray.main(IntArray.java:17)
```

There is a *dll* file named *IntArray.dll* in the directory *W:\elita\jnitesters\workspace\c\IntArray\bin\Debug*

Comment: @UNNI yes. Netbeans + Code::Blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine ! But there is one thing you should attempt. Permanently delete all sorts of files(including .dll file) created by the IDE *code::blocks* . And then rebuild your program. Omit **MACROS** if any ! Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I can't see anything obvious, but a couple of things to try:

1) Specify the full path in your `System.load()` The stack trace is a bit confusing that it's indicating sumArray() being called by the 17th line which is the static, so I don't know what to make of that.

2) Put a try/catch block around your `System.load()`

3) Try defining your method like this:

```
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Package_IntArray_sumArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jintArray arr)
 {
     /*Implement Native Method Here*/
 }
```

Maybe the method is not being exported in your .dll file which is why it's not finding it.

Comment: even when i give the full path i get the exception :`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no W:/elita/jnitesters/workspace/c/IntArray/bin/Debug/IntArray.dll in java.library.path`

Comment: You get the exception in the System.load()? You added the try/catch around that? This probably indicates then that it's not finding the .dll file in that location. Can you double check that it's actually there and accessible?

Comment: Can you use http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html to see that your DLL has the correct method exported?

Answer (score 0):

You have already created a folder `elita` under `lib` forlder of your Netbeans project.Copy your .dll to that folder.Now in NetBeans IDE, right click and select Project properties->Run->VM Options:-`Djava.library.path=lib/elita`

Then run your program from IDE itself.

Comment: where do i need to create the lib folder ? [Is this ok ?](http://i50.tinypic.com/20fby9.jpg). This was just inside the netbeans project folder

Comment: Yes...under the lib folder create a folder called elite and copy that .dll

Comment: Your path still shows old only.Change it to lib/elita and execute via an IDE.

Comment: gives the same exception after i execute it via netbeans

Comment: can you paste here VM options?

Comment: How does this differ from manually setting the path during runtime ?